# WebProxy - use C# code or machine to configure

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I am writing a .NET (C#) windows application. I have an HttpClientHandler for which I setup a WebProxy.

I don't know if is it better to set no proxy and use the machine proxy settings? or set up the HttpClient to use a WebProxy inside the code.
In both cases, the result would be the same - the request will use the same proxy.

Is there a more reliable or "industry accepted" choice between the two?

What happens if both the machine settings sets up the proxy, and the code does it too?

ADDITIONAL NOTE - both choices are mine to make. I do not depend on a customer for any of those choices. The question is pure in the sense of reliability as I found that with machine set WebProxy settings, every so often my clients failed to go trough.

Comment: Don't set it in code. There is no way your code can know what the proxy is for all environments your code might run in, both now _and in the future_. One day your organisation will change their proxy details and then all your applications will stop working! HttpClient supports standard proxy config by default for a reason - use it!

Comment: In both cases I use external configurable items that are under my control. I do not depend on the clients in any way. Is just that I get some failures when the proxy settings are set for the machine.

Comment: In that case, if you have a specific proxy requirement that you cannot satisfy with the default proxy support, then you pretty much have to add your own proxy in code. If you can get away with using the defaults then don't reinvent the wheel. There shouldn't be any reliability concerns with either approach - I wonder if you should ask about those as a specific question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just recently went through a very similar issue as this while dealing with  the WebProxy for the first time.

I have a HttpClientHandler that sets up my web proxy as well. My team and I chose to handle this in code because it was easier to test and verify via unit tests.

To make this configurable, we have the app read in the configuration details from a secure configuration that is set at install time. If the proxy configuration changes this can be updated in the config file.
This also works for us because our tool is a data aggregation tool that sends to a very specific web API.

I used the WebProxy with an HttpClientHandler with my HttpClient to do all of this.

Here are some links that helped me out:
[MSDN Solution](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fcc6e221-ae8e-4ca6-851a-725f455e3d59/how-to-use-proxy-in-http-client?forum=csharpgeneral)
[.Net WebProxy doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webproxy?view=net-5.0)